# How to dismiss an expanded drop down menu that is not focusable when clicking the button that normally expands it

Tags: drop-down-menu, android-jetpack-compose

I have a button to expand a drop down menu in my Composable. I set my drop down menu to not take focus using `PopupProperties(focusable = false)` (I have to do this so the keyboard does not get dismissed when expanding the drop down menu). Now I have an issue where clicking the expand button to show menu when the menu is already expanded causes two recompositions, resulting in the menu still being expanded and not dismissed as expected. The first recomposition, it dismisses the menu and sets my rememebered value for `expanded` to false. Then when the button's `onClick` lambda is called, `expanded` gets set back to true, causing a second recomposition that expands the menu again. How do I allow dismissing the menu by clicking the expand button if it is already expanded?

```
var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
Box() {
    IconButton(onClick = { expanded = true })
    DropdownMenu(
        expanded = expanded,
        onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
        properties = PopupProperties(focusable = false)
    )
}
```

Comment: You can assign the expanded state to true by checking whether it's false or not. If false, assign to true. If true, ignore. Or, alternatively, you can also introduce `derivedStateOf` which will only recompose whenever your value changes from one state to another. Otherwise, it will not recompose.

Comment: @AhsanUllahRasel Unfortunately the first approach won't work because `expanded` gets set to false immediately after the `onDismissRequest` so by the time the click is registered, it will always be false. For the same reason, I don't think the second approach would work. I have tried both so any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: The best solution I have found is to introduce a delay using `System.currentTimeMillis()` of 100 milliseconds. This mostly works well but seems very hacky. It will actually not expand the menu again if user clicks the button while it's expanded. Since this should occur faster than 100 milliseconds I think this can work.

Comment: looks like a bug to me, since popup registered the click it shouldn't be passed down to the view. I suggest you create a bug report on [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/new?component=612128), meanwhile delay workaround sound fine.

Comment: @PhilDukhov I assumed this was working as intended since the menu doesn't have focus, shouldn't that mean whatever else is focusable will react to user input?

Comment: @mpellegr according to the doc, focusable should only control "IME events and key presses".

Comment: @PhilDukhov oh good point, will log one. If you want to make this an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I could find is a hacky work around to use a 100 milliseconds delay before reacting to a click on the button. Works well for the most part but really quick taps will appear to "do nothing".

```
    var dismissedTimeMillis by remember { mutableStateOf<Long?>(null) }
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Box() {
       IconButton(onClick = 
           dismissedTimeMillis.let {
               if (it == null || (System.currentTimeMillis() - it) > 100L) {
                   expanded = true
               }
           })
       DropdownMenu(
           expanded = expanded,
           onDismissRequest = { 
               expanded = false 
               dismissedTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
           },
           properties = PopupProperties(focusable = false)
       )
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug, since according to the documentation, [`focusable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/window/PopupProperties#focusable()) should only control "IME events and key presses".

So delay workaround should work until it's fixed.

Comment: Actually, I think it's working as intended. The focusable property only applies to IME events and key presses in the menu (hence why the class is called `PopupProperties`). So if it is set to false, that means the menu no longer receives these events, the rest of the app will. 

I think my best bet is to turn off the ability the ability to press the button that showed the popup in the first place. This should still register as "clicking outside" the menu so it should still dismiss, and not trigger the button click on recomposition and thus not show the menu again.